# Is a passport needed when flying within Mexico as a U.S permanent resident?

Tags: air-travel, usa, legal, mexico, residency

I am a permanent resident (U.S) and I'm crossing the border into Mexico and taking a flight to Mexico city. The passport from my home nation is expired and I'm trying to avoid the last minute 500 mile+ trip to the nearest embassy. My question is, can I get on the plane with my green card or state license? or my expired passport and birth certificate? also, can i get the FMM/tourist card with my drivers license? all the official information says i need a valid passport, but other travelers have had different experiences, does it just depend on the officer? I already purchased my flight!

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you must have a valid passport to enter Mexico, see e.g. the following links:

Mexican Consulate in San Francisco,
http://consulmex.sre.gob.mx/sanfrancisco/index.php/visas-traveling-to-mexico

> 1. Effective March 1st 2010, all US Citizens are required to present U. S. Passport or U.S. Passport Card when entering Mexico (traveling by air, land or sea).
> 2. US Permanent Residents traveling by air, land or sea to Mexico are required to present a valid Permanent Resident Card. **Plus a valid and not expired passport or travel document.** If you do not have that card consult other documentation also accepted to prove the US Permanent Residence status.

Mexican Consulate in Detroit, http://consulmex.sre.gob.mx/detroit/index.php/info-english

> US Permanent Residents traveling by air, land or sea to Mexico are required to present a valid Permanent Residency Card, **as well as a valid passport** from their country of origin or travel document.

Mexican Consulate in Anchorage
http://consulmex.sre.gob.mx/anchorage/index.php?option=com_content&id=34&Itemid=31

> All permanent  residents of the United  States  who are holders of  a “Permanent Resident Card”, also known as “green card”, who want to travel to Mexico as tourists just need to present **their passport** and “Green Card”.

More importantly, Timatic (the database that airlines use) says that

> Passport required.
>
> - **Passports and/or passport replacing documents must be valid
>     on arrival.**
> - Warning: if departing from the USA (regardless of any destination passport exemptions), a valid passport and/oraccepted departure document For details, click here is required by the US immigration authorities.
>
> Passport Exemptions:
>
> - Holders of emergency or temporary passports.

Airline employees will use this Timatic information when they decide whether to let you board your flight to Mexico. **Most likely, they will not let you board the plane** (even if an immigration officer in Mexico may let you in).

I would suggest that you contact a Mexican consulate and your airline, and double check with them whether you need a valid passport.

Comment: yea, the airline says my green card or drivers license would be enough, the consulate tells me i need my passport so I don't know who has more authority.

Comment: @Lani You can exit the US on your green card, but Need a passport to enter Mexico. However, if your nationality normally requires a Mexican visa, your green card exempts you from that

Comment: @Lani I would trust the consulate over the airline