# Does a US permanent resident need a tourist visa to visit Mexico?

Tags: visas, mexico, us-residents, jordanian-citizens

If a person is a permanent resident of the united states, and holds only a Jordanian passport, will they be required to apply for a tourist visa to go to Mexico for a short vacation?

No, it is not a duplicate of [Is a passport needed when flying within Mexico as a U.S permanent resident?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/37722/is-a-passport-needed-when-flying-within-mexico-as-a-u-s-permanent-resident)
That question is asking about getting onto a flight departing from Mexico.

Comment: No.  Even those who hold a US visitor's visa are exempt from the requirement to hold a Mexican tourist visa.

Comment: @phoog Does that negate the need for an FMM tourist permit usually obtained as you enter the country?

Comment: @Midavalo I do not know.

Comment: @Dorothy the duplicate you proposed is about domestic flights in Mexico.  This question is about entering Mexico, which is a rather different question.

Comment: @user102008 No. Same answer, different question. They are indian passport holders. This question is Jordinian passport holders

Answer (score 4):

#### No

I searched on Google for "mexico visa", and the first hit shown to me was the following official site of the Mexican government:

https://consulmex.sre.gob.mx/sanfrancisco/index.php/visas-traveling-to-mexico

> A.      Effective March 1st 2010, all visitors traveling to Mexico either by air, land or sea are required to present a valid (non-expired) Passport or Travel Document from their country to enter Mexico.
>
> B.     With the purpose of facilitating and promoting travel to Mexico, effective May 2016 all those foreign nationals, regardless of their nationality, visiting Mexico for tourism, business or transit are NOT required to obtain a Mexican visa IF they hold a valid (non-expired) Visa or Permanent Residence of any of this countries: United States of America, Canada, Japan, United Kingdom or Schengen area (European Union).